# How to obtain Stack Overflow questions for posting in my blog?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, api

Is it possible to get information from questions on Stack Overflow and post it to my blog?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, through a variety of methods.  All data is licensed [CC-BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/), which you should understand before you do this, but in short it allows you to take and use the questions, answers, comments, etc as long as you provide attribution (ie, a link back to the original question).

You can get the entire database through a [data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/) which is produced every two months, or more conveniently you can get data on the fly and up to date from the [stack overflow API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help).

Answer (score 1):

Many blogging platforms have plugins to take rss feeds and repost them to your blog — or even better, just queue them (so you can approve just the ones you want).  Usually appropriate credits will be added, and you will need to make sure this is configured to follow the license terms specified by Stack Overflow (click the cc image link at the bottom).  Obviously, if these are your own answers/questions, then as author you retain copyright and can do whatever you want.

Stack Overflow has numerous rss feeds that may interest you: new questions, per tag, and per user, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this StackTack application

[StackTack, a JavaScript widget you can stick anywhere](https://stackapps.com/questions/518/stacktack-a-javascript-widget-you-can-stick-anywhere)

You can embed the questions in your blog, and since it is using api, you don't need to worry about new answers or update info also.

Comment: Actually, i don't want to embed my questions to my blogs. i want to embed questions with delphi tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can just post a link to the question?

In this case, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385774/how-to-get-stackoverflow-questions-tobe-posted-in-a-blog`.

Can you be more specific about what you're after?

Comment: No, i don't mean that. I'm delphi programmer. I want to get delphi reated questions from stackoverflow to be posted in my blogs. So.. every one could watch n then click those question. it may be something like RSS

Comment: If people want to follow delpi questions on SO.. why do they not just follow them directly on SO?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible but not a good idea. Duplicate content can(and will) seriously hurt your blog ranking. If you decide to do that, you should at least get a permission and provide a link to the original question, though.

Comment: Permission is already granted as long as you follow the license terms.